# How to make only the text label 'FontWeight: Bold' on Tooltip EChartJS

Tags: charts, echarts

I need help here from you guys, Is there a way to make the text label in my tooltip BOLD ?? I mean only the label.

[image: This is my chart]

I try using the `fontWeight: 'bold'` but all text on my tooltip is bold.
i just want the label bold, not the data.
[image]

this is my script

```
var echartsConfig = function() {  
if( $('#e_chart_07').length > 0 ){
                var eChart_07 = echarts.init(document.getElementById('e_chart_07'));
                var option07 = {
                    legend: {
                        display: true,
                        position: 'top',
                        labels: {
                          boxWidth: 15,
                          fontColor: 'black'
                        }
                    },
                    color: ['blue','purple','orange','red'],     
                    tooltip: {
                        show: true,
                        trigger: 'axis',
                        backgroundColor: '#fff',
                        borderRadius:10,
                        padding:10,
                        axisPointer:{
                            lineStyle:{
                                width:0,
                            }
                        },
                        textStyle: {
                            color: '#324148',
                            fontFamily: '"Poppins", sans-serif',
                            fontSize: 12,
                            // fontWeight: 'bold'
                        }
                    },
                    grid: {
                        top: '13%',
                        left: '3%',
                        right: '3%',
                        bottom: '3%',
                        containLabel: true
                    },
                    xAxis : [
                        {
                            type : 'category',
                            data : [<?php foreach($duta as $dba){
                                    echo '"'.$dba->agj_month_name.' '.$dba->agj_year.'",';
                                    }?>
                                    ],
                            axisLine: {
                                show:false
                            },
                            axisTick: {
                                show:false
                            },
                            axisLabel: {
                                textStyle: {
                                    color: 'Black'
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    yAxis : [
                        {
                            type : 'value',
                            axisLine: {
                                show:false
                            },
                            axisTick: {
                                show:false
                            },
                            axisLabel: {
                                textStyle: {
                                    color: 'Black'
                                }
                            },
                            splitLine: {
                                lineStyle: {
                                    color: 'transparent',
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    series : [
                        {
                            name:'0-30  ',
                            type:'bar',
                            barMaxWidth: 30,
                            data:[<?php foreach($duta as $dba){
                                    echo '"'.$dba->agj_030.'",';
                                    }?>],
                            itemStyle: {
                                normal: {
                                    barBorderRadius: [3, 3, 0, 0] ,
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            name:'31-60 ',
                            type:'bar',
                            barMaxWidth: 30,
                            data:[<?php foreach($duta as $dba){
                                    echo '"'.$dba->agj_3160.'",';
                                    }?>],
                            itemStyle: {
                                normal: {
                                    barBorderRadius: [3, 3, 0, 0] ,
                                }
                            },
                        },
                        {
                            name:'61-90 ',
                            type:'bar',
                            barMaxWidth: 30,
                            data:[<?php foreach($duta as $dba){
                                    echo '"'.$dba->agj_6190.'",';
                                    }?>],
                            itemStyle: {
                                normal: {
                                    barBorderRadius: [3, 3, 0, 0] ,
                                }
                            },
                        },
                        {
                            name:'>90   ',
                            type:'bar',
                            barMaxWidth: 30,
                            data:[<?php foreach($duta as $dba){
                                    echo '"'.$dba->agj_more90.'",';
                                    }?>],
                            itemStyle: {
                                normal: {
                                    barBorderRadius: [3, 3, 0, 0] ,
                                }
                            },
                        }
                    ]
                };
                eChart_07.setOption(option07);
                eChart_07.resize();
            }
```

```
<div id="e_chart_07" class="echart" style="height:294px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use formatter for that. you can see the code below.

```
tooltip: {
                    show: true,
                    trigger: 'axis',
                    backgroundColor: '#fff',
                    borderRadius:10,
                    padding:10,
                    axisPointer:{
                        lineStyle:{
                            width:0,
                        }
                    },
                    textStyle: {
                        color: '#324148',
                        fontFamily: '"Poppins", sans-serif',
                        fontSize: 12,
                        // fontWeight: 'bold'
                    },
                    formatter: (params) => {
                        let dataStr = `<div>${params[0].name}</div>`;
                        console.log(params[0]);
                        params.forEach((item) => {
                            let valueCal = ((params[1].value/params[0].value)*100).toFixed(0).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") == undefined ? "-" : ((params[1].value/params[0].value)*100).toFixed(0).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
                            dataStr = `
                                <div><strong>Persentase</strong></div>
                                <div>
                                    <i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:${item.color}"></i>
                                    ${params[1].seriesName} :
                                    ${valueCal}
                                </div>
                            `;
                        });
                        return dataStr;
                    },
                },
```